# Excel protected column with Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have an excel sheet that has a column with a formula embedded in it. I protected this column to hide the formula and prevent the user from making changes, however, the user wants to be able to add rows, and if a row is added then the formula is not copied to the new row. Any suggestions?

Comment: Turn the entire range into a table. Then have the user use Right-Click>>Insert>>TableRowsBelow to insert and the formula will copy down.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. But the sheet is protected so the user cant right click and add row.

Comment: Then you'll need to write some VBA to do the row insert.